# Hibernate H2 database locks after project rebuild

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat7, h2

I am setting up a Spring hibernate H2 application. When the server starts everything works but after an update (rebuild project in eclipse without restarting Tomcat) I get the following error messages saying that the database file can't be accessed.

Error Messages:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:/home/bob/dataStore.mv.db [1.4.187/7]

java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException

org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use:
```

After Googling this error I tried adding `File_LOCK=NO` and `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE` to the URL but no luck.

`Context.xml` file

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
<!--       <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/dataStore;FILE_LOCK=NO;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE" /> -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:~/dataStore;FILE_LOCK=NO;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;MVCC=TRUE" />

        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

What can I do so that the database does not get locked every time the project is rebuilt.

Also, eclipse is rebuilding the application after everytime the database is updated. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`, from the Spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource.embedded)

> If, for whatever reason, you do configure the connection URL for an embedded database, care should be taken to ensure that the database’s automatic shutdown is disabled. If you’re using H2 you should use DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE to do so.

Answer (score -1):

if need to create multipul connecation then you need to use below code :

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:\Database\Data\production;"/>
```

Comment: The code above is not valid for spring. resulting error message `Invalid property 'javax' of bean class`